# Как прописать атрибуты макета блока?

Tags: magento

Я пишу модуль для magento1.9. Помогите пожалуйста выставить атрибуты для 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/kalinin_form.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
    <kalininform_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="kalininform/form" template="Kalinin_Form/index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </kalininform_index_index>
</layout>
```

Как видите, сейчас у меня атрибут type(а может быть и другие) установлен неверно.

Проблема в том, что браузер показывает страницу с пустой областью контента по адресу localhost/magento3/index.php/form

Привожу остальной код модуля.

app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/Kalinin_Form/index.phtml:

```
<?php
echo('qqqqqqqqqqqqq');
```

app/code/local/Kalinin/Form/controllers/IndexController.php:

```
<?php
class Kalinin_Form_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {                     
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

app/code/local/Kalinin/Form/Block/Form.php:

```
<?php
class Kalinin_Form_Block_Form extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    public function getNewsCollection()
    {
        Mage::log("Your Log Message");    
        return true;
    }

}
```

app/code/local/Kalinin/Form/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Kalinin_Form>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Kalinin_Form>
    </modules>
    <frontend>    
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <kalininform>
                    <file>kalinin_form.xml</file>
                </kalininform>
            </updates>
        </layout>           
        <routers>
            <kalininform>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Kalinin_Form</module>
                    <frontName>form</frontName>
                </args>
            </kalininform>
        </routers>
    </frontend>    
    <global>        
        <blocks>
            <Kalinin_Form>
                <class>Kalinin_Form_Block</class>
            </Kalinin_Form>
        </blocks>      
    </global>    
</config>
```

Вообще у меня проблема с пониманием атрубутов в app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/kalinin_form.xml. Официальной документации нет. Буду благодарен, если объясните что к чему.

ps:
при этом в system.log и в exception.log ничего не пишется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых правим конфиг заменив это

```
<global>        
    <blocks>
        <Kalinin_Form>
            <class>Kalinin_Form_Block</class>
        </Kalinin_Form>
    </blocks>      
</global>
```

на это

```
<global>        
    <blocks>
        <kalininform>
            <class>Kalinin_Form_Block</class>
        </kalininform>
    </blocks>      
</global>
```

тут пишеться не название модуля а ключ. 
Далее разберёмся с layout-тами

```
<layout>
    <kalininform_index_index> <!-- это ModuleName().'_'.ControllerName.'_'.ActionName -->
        <reference name="content"> <!-- обновляем контент -->
            <block  type="kalininform/form" name="kalininform" template="Kalinin_Form/index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </kalininform_index_index>
</layout>
```

теперь разберём секцию block.

`type='kalininform/form` это тип блока при рендере внутри магенто вызовиться метод `getBlockSingleton`, и в него будет передан этот ключ `kalininform/form` первая часть до слэша это ключ в конфиге для блока модуля т.е. ништо иное как вот эта часть:

```
    <global>        
        <blocks>
            <kalininform>
                <class>Kalinin_Form_Block</class>
            </kalininform>
        </blocks>      
    </global>
```

Из всех конфигов он выберет по ключу название класса `class`,в нашем случае это `Kalinin_Form_Block`.

Вторая часть ключа это путь до имени класса в lowercase режиме, т.е. в нашем случае magento возьмёт `form` из ключа и преобразует в `Form` а далее взяв предыдущий класс name (реализация namespace), она подставит этот кусок в конец с нижнем подчёркиванием, в результате получиться име конечного класса блока `Kalinin_Form_Block_Form` и от сюда она подгрузит следующий фаил `Kalinin\Form\Block\Form.php`.

Что же касаеться `template` это относительный путь до шаблона в директории `template` текущей темы.
 т.е. если `template="Kalinin_Form/index.phtml"` должен находиться в директории `template/Kalinin_Form/`.

Далее вы забыли про `name` шаблона в контексте блока `content` это в принципе не критично, но индетификация блоков идёт по name так што лучше его прописать.

Есть ещё несколько опций на которых я не буду останавливаться это `output`,`as`,`after` и т.д.

**Методы дебага шаблонов:**

1. Включить отображение путей до шаблонов `система->конфигурация-> для разработчиков` переключить store view в левом углу на store сайта далее находим пункт шаблоны и включаем опции `подсказка путей шаблона` и `подсказки классов шаблонов`.
2. Мониторинг логов, `tailf -1000 /magentoroot/var/log/exception.log`  и `tailf -1000 /magentoroot/var/log/system.log` где `magentoroot` путь до корневой директории magento.
3. Мониторинг логов сервера.
4. Ну и больше для самой magento, копируем файлик `/magentoroot/errors/local.xml.sample` в `/magentoroot/errors/local.xml` если его нет, либо приводим его к виду

   default
       
           print

для девелоперского окружения естевственно.